# jQuery select multiple :nth-child()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selection

This is my table , use tr, and td.

```
NAME Address CITY STATE 
ABC   123    A     CA 
AB8   123    B     CA
AFC   456    B     TX 
POI   985    C     KJ
```

After document ready, it will hide all  already.

Now I want a line to show all tr have:
-> Column (4) = CA "and" Column (3) = B

I tired my code:

```
$("table[id=maintablex] tr td:nth-child(4):contains('CA'), table[id=maintablex] tr td:nth-child(3):contains('B')").closest('tr').show();
```

But it show everything have (4) = CA , and (3) = B... My code was "OR" , can some one help me this one ?

Added FULL HTML CODE:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUF</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>TX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>TX</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script language="Javascript">
$("table[id=table] tr").hide();

// Code show here


</script>
```

The result I want to show is only :

```
AB8   123    B     CA
```

Comment: I would recommend replacing `table[id=maintablex]` with `#maintablex`, it will perform **much** faster. Here is a jsperf to prove: http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-vs-id-attribute

Comment: yes, add #table , it run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it this way:

```
$("table[id=maintablex] tr td:nth-child(3):contains('B')", 
    $("table[id=maintablex] tr td:nth-child(4):contains('CA')")
).closest('tr').show();
```

---

I don't know if this is faster, but based on @Jasper 's response, why not do this:

```
//select the table, find all `<td>` elements that contain `CA` and iterate through each of them
$('#table')
    .find('td:nth-child(4):contains("CA")')
    .closest('tr')
    .find('td:nth-child(3):contains("B")')
    .closest('tr')
    .addClass('active');
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQMXe/

Comment: Yea, now it work. But i don't know it  faster or not. but I like it.. I really don't like Loop $each

Answer (score 1):

Your very first selector is always going to match rows where State = CA AND where State = B.
I would break this into two pieces.  Haven't tested this code but it should get you close...

```
var stateRows = ("#maintablex tr td:nth-child(4):contains('CA')").parent();
var matchRows = stateRows.find("td:nth-child(3):contains('B')").parent();

matchRows.doWhateverYouLikeWithTheResults();
```

Comment: Neat code, easy to test in Firebug. I only had to fix the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

JS--

```
//select the table, find all `<td>` elements that contain `CA` and iterate through each of them
$('#maintablex').find('td:nth-child(4):contains("CA")').each(function (index, value) {

    //un-hide the parent `<tr>` element of this `<td>` by adding the `active` class to the `<tr>`
    $(this).parents('tr:first').addClass('active');
});
```

CSS--

```
/*Hide all the table rows by default*/
tr {
    display : none;
}

/*declare a class that shows the table rows when added to them*/
tr.active {
    display : table-row;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated the above code to only look for the third column in each row (I had omitted that part of the answer before).

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Mp7Jq/3/

Comment: ty Bro, but the table is gonna have like 500 - 1000 rows. So, use .each() is still fast? I think .each gonna slow with loop, that why I want to try 1 selecting with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each($('table#table tr td:nth-child(4):contains("CA")').parent(),function(){
    if(($.inArray(this, $('table#table tr td:nth-child(3):contains("B")').parent())) > -1){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. :)